# OpenVPN gui is empty when trying to connect

Tags: openvpn

When trying to connect through the openVPN gui I just get a blank window that produces no logs (the log file is created but is empty). After about a minute I get a message saying "Connecting to myVpn has failed". When I try to run it from the console by "openvpn.exe myVpn.ovpn" I get: "Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: myVpn.ovpn.

I am aware of the fact that this is a duplicate of [OpenVPN GUI window is empty. Why can't I connect to my VPN?](https://superuser.com/questions/666452/openvpn-gui-window-is-empty-why-cant-i-connect-to-my-vpn) however the answer posted there only points to debugging openvpn through the console.

My knowledge about such topics is limited so the debugging information does not help me.

Additional information:
 - I run openVPN in administrator mode,
 - I'm on windows 7,
 - I tried 3 different versions and have installed them in several ways (including through safe mode),
 - The "tap" connection has a message/error of unplugged

Thanks for any help.

--edit--
My config:

```
#Plik wygenerowany przez instalator v.2.0.9-gui-1.0.3
remote myadress.com
dev    tun
#local  0.0.0.0
proto  udp
port   1194
cipher AES-256-CBC
client
nobind
mute-replay-warnings
persist-key
persist-tun
resolv-retry infinite
ns-cert-type server
#pull
#tls-client
comp-lzo
verb 3
ca   "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\keys-hq\\cacert.pem"
cert "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\keys-hq\\myname.crt"
key  "C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\keys-hq\\myname.key"
```

Notes:
 - The first line is in Polish and says that the file has been generated by the gui installator,
 - I did not create this config,
 - I have changed the real address and my name to "myaddress.com" and "myname" respectively.

Comment: 1. You have to debug this using the console. 2. Try again but specify the full path to the config file.

Answer (score 1):

> I run openVPN in administrator mode

You **must** also run `openvpn-gui.exe` by `<right-click>"Run as Administrator"` .. even though you are in admin mode.  This is a `Windows` *security measure*.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ment. I should have probably used "openVPN GUI" that would have been more clear.

Comment: > I get: "Options error: In [CMD-LINE]:1: Error opening configuration file: myVpn.ovpn -- This indicates there is a syntax error on line 1 -- Please add your config file to your question

Comment: I have updated the OP.

Comment: Delete **all** the lines that start with `#` and try again

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help.

Comment: Run the config in an `elevated privilege command prompt` and add the log file result.  Also, make sure you are running the **correct** config file.

Comment: Do you still get the same error ? This problem may be better dealt with on the [OpenVPN Forum](https://forums.openvpn.net/configuration-f6.html)

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a mix of three errors.

The first problem had something to do with rights that the admin should have given me, this is all I know.

The second problem was that 'invisible' characters were inserted into my config somehow (sublime text?).

The third problem was that we have both cable and wireless connection and they have different configs. I was only given the wi-fi one.