# Connecting to OpenVPN client has failed - only the GUI fails (command line and services are OK)

Tags: windows, windows-10, openvpn

I suddenly have exactly the same problem as in [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/666452/openvpn-gui-window-is-empty-why-cant-i-connect-to-my-vpn) (blank OpenVPN GUI window, the after some time a popup stating that the connection failed) but the solution does not help. Specifically, when the issue happens:

- OpenVPN Daemon (which is actually `openvpn.exe`) is running
- it is listening on port `25340`

Moreover, when starting on a command line `"C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin\openvpn.exe" --config "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config\client.ovpn"` the connection to the server goes through (the tunnel is brought up and works fine)

OpenVPN GUI used to work perfectly, it suddenly exhibits this issue without any changes in the configuration, nor in the version. I reinstalled the latest version (2.3.11) just in case. The `openvpn.exe` and `openvpn-gui.exe` files are configured to be run under Administrator privileges.

I can also successfully (= the tunnel is up) start the OpenVPN service. This brings in an OpenVPN Daemon (`openvpn.exe`), without any `LISTEN` ports (which I belive is normal as there is no interaction with a client, as it is the case with the GUI).

Is there anything else I can do to troubleshoot?

Comment: You cannot run the OpenVPN Service and The OpenVPN-GUI at the same time.